# optlen parameter in getsockopt()

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I went through the documentation, but still didn't get what does optlen do in `getsockopt(int s, int level, int optname, void *optval,
               socklen_t *optlen)` , can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set it to the size of the data item you're receiving the option value into. On return the size may have been adjusted.

The documentation does say that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. what does it mean 'the size may have been adjusted'? how?

Comment: What do you mean 'how'? You're passing a pointer to the length, so the caller can update it.

Comment: I was asking `optlen` not `optval`, did you mixed them?

Comment: Certainly not. You pass the address of both of them, and they can therefore both get updated. Look at your own sample in your comment to @demo.b's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Optlen is an in-out parameter used to specify the length of the buffer.

Comment: I encountered this line `getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF,
         &sockbufsize, &intlen`, where `unsigned int intlen = sizeof(int)`, so intlen is 4 here not the length of buffer? why we need to specify the Optlen here if we already have `sockbufsize` ?

Comment: @Blake getsockopt() doesn't have any other way of knowing about the 4 byte length. It doesn't know that 'sockbufsize' is an 'int'.

Comment: I still don't get it, why we need to set `intlen = sizeof(int)`?

Comment: @Blake Sigh. You need to tell getsockopt() how long the data area pointed to by 'optval' is. It doesn't know that it's an int, a long, whatever. To getsockopt() it is just a void*. See the signature that you quoted yourself in your question.